# Cross-platform defining #define for macros __FUNCTION__ and __func__

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros

Compiling with gcc 4.4.2 and WinXP Visual Studio C++ 2008

```
#if defined ( WIN32 )
#define __FUNCTION__ __func__
#endif
```

As I want to use the macro to display the function name. I have done the above so I can cross-platform, and use the same **func** when compiling on linux or windows.

However, when I am compiling on WinXP I get the following error:

```
__func__ undeclared identifier
```

Can I not #define a macro like this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: You should use #if defined(_MSC_VER) rather than #if defined (_WIN32).  The question is not which OS you are using.  The question is which compiler you are using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you have your `#define` backward.  If you want to use `__func__` on both platforms, and WIN32 has `__FUNCTION__` but not `__func__`, you need to do this instead:

```
#if defined ( WIN32 )
#define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#endif
```

There may be a better way to know whether you need to define `__func__` or not, but this quick hack should do the trick.

Remember, on compilers that support the `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__` keywords, they're not macros so you can't do the following (since `#ifndef __func__` isn't valid):

```
#ifndef __func__
#define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#endif
```

From the C99 spec:

> 6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers
>
> 1 The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But has got me thinking. When you say that __FUNCTION__ and __func__ are not macros. Why can't you define in a #define. Also how can we know if it is a macro or keyword? Many thanks.

Comment: That's a good question -- I guess you have to go to the ANSI spec (or Google) to find out.  In this case, `__func__` is a "predefined identifier" and based on the description, acts like a static const variable defined in the function.

In my example above, the part that won't work is `#ifndef __func__` since `__func__` isn't a defined macro visible to the macro pre-processor.

Answer (score 6):

The `__FUNCTION__` macro is pre-defined in the MSVC compiler.  You'll need to make it look like this:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define __FUNCTION__ __func__
#endif
```

Or the other way around, if you prefer:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#endif
```

Comment: I tried that, and still got the same error. I also tried this as well in the condition (__MSVC__), and got the same error. Any more suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe its me, but when I try those 2 I get the error: "#if[n]def expected an identifer". Thanks.

Comment: @robUK - oops, the original snippet got me in trouble.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen the brackets. I guess I am too used to using the if defined () with the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `__func__` without any explicit macros in any compiler that supports C99.

Comment: Yes, I can use that in c89/c99. However, visual studio 2008 uses __FUNCTION__. I was trying #define so that I can use the same macro for both windows and linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course `#define` such a macro. Every instance of `FUNCTION` is then replaced by `__func__`. However, obviosuly your compiler doesn't know `__func__`. I believe VC knows `__FUNCTION__`, so

```
#if defined ( WIN32 )
#  define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#endif
```

might do.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` isn't a macro, so you can't have a #ifdef on it.  As with `__func__`, it's either a keyword for the compiler or it isn't.