# __func__ C++11 function's local predefined variable, won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, standards-compliance

The `__func__` C++11 local predefined variable of a function does not compile in Visual Studio 2012 Professional (with Update 1 installed) with the default built-in Visual Studio 2012 (v110) compiler or the November 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012) compiler. However, the editor does not complain with any red squiggly underline under `__func__`. `__func__` is supposed to give the name of its containing function, in this case `foo`, but this neither compiles nor make the editor complain:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    cout << __func__ << endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the compiler error:

```
error C2065: '__func__' : undeclared identifier
```

Am I missing something in my code or will this work in a future update?

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx?PageIndex=11) it says the support is "partial". Not sure what's meant by that.

Comment: "However, the editor does not complain with any red squiggly underline under `__func__`." -- *Never* rely on red squiggles to tell you if your code will compile or not. IntelliSense and the actual compiler front-end are developed by different people. If in doubt, the compiler is correct, because that's what creates your binaries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MSVC's C99 support is quite poor in general; your best bet might be to use the MSVC-specific `__FUNCTION__` macro. See this question for details: [Cross-platform defining #define for macros __FUNCTION__ and __func__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281970/cross-platform-defining-define-for-macros-function-and-func)

**Update (2015-06-22)**: Visual Studio 2015 supports `__func__`, see the [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Compile the program using C++11 standards as `__func__` is C++11 feature.

So, compile it like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo
```

Comment: The OP isn't using GCC. MSVC doesn't support any `-std=c++11` command-line option. Please take a bit more time reading the question before answering, this could have been a good answer to a different question, just not to this question.