# Why is constant char pointer at beginning of every function used?

Tags: c++

What is purpose of first line of function?

```
void  foo::bar()

{

  const char * function_name = "bar"; // <<< WHY??

  /* Code */

  /* More Code */

  /* Waiting for function_name to be used !!!*/

  /* Wow it is totally useless?*/
  return; 
}
```

`

This are used every where in code designed by experienced people, no macros to print . Does it carry any trick?

Comment: Can you show an example of where this is common usage? Perhaps link to an open source project? I've only seen this done in cases where it **is** used, for logging, and therefore sometimes is still present in small functions with no logs.

Comment: That's a question that only the person that put it there could answer (I suspect it is a debugging aid, or relates to a macro that *used to exists*)

Comment: @BoBTFish Unfortunately this is in proprietary code. I searched for debug macro that prints like "__FUNCTION__" but there is none. As it is not used, compiler removed it with full confidence at O1 itself. Everyone else working on code are following same *culture*

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this program's header files contain, somewhere, a custom `assert` macro reading something like

```
#define fooco_assert(expr) \
    ((void) ((expr) || \
     fooco_assert_failed(#expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, function_name)))

extern int fooco_assert_failed(const char *expr, const char *srcfile,
                               int lineno, const char *fnname);
```

To support this, the authors made it a style rule that there would be a definition of `function_name` at the beginning of every single function, so that they could, in the future, add calls to `fooco_assert` as necessary without having to think about whether or not `function_name` was available.  As you have noticed, the compiler will not bother emitting the strings into the compiled program unless they are actually used, so it isn't an efficiency issue.

It certainly *is* a speedbump to reading and editing the program, though.  C++11 compilers provide a predefined variable called [`__func__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126387/func-c11-functions-local-predefined-variable-wont-compile) holding the name of the current function; this could be used instead.  This feature was added to the *C* standard in 1999, and many C++ compilers adopted it almost immediately.  Other C++ compilers don't have `__func__` but do have an equivalent proprietary extension, e.g. `__FUNCTION__`.  Note that these are *not* macros;

```
#ifndef __func__
#define __func__ "<unavailable>"
#endif
```

will not detect whether `__func__` is available.  You would have to do something like this instead (off the top of my head, not tested at all):

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || __GNUC__ >= 3
// __func__ is available in C++11, and in GCC >= 3.0
#elif _MSC_VER || __GNUC__
// pre-C++11 MSVC and ancient versions of GCC call this
// feature __FUNCTION__ instead
#define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#elif ...
// ... etc etc for all other compilers you care about 
#else
#define __func__ "<unavailable>"
#endif
```

Comment: Surprised __func__ was introduced only in C++11 !

Comment: @P.P. It was added to *C* in 1999, but the C++ standard received only minor revisions between 1998 and 2011.  Many C++ compilers did pick it up in advance, though, or they had equivalent extensions; I'll add something about that.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that at one point, the function had code that looked like this:

```
const char * function_name = "bar";
Loggers::get_logger() << "Entered function " << function_name << "\n";
```

Speaking as someone who writes Enterprise Code, I've seen constructs like that quite often. Perhaps the logging was removed or part of a meta-programming template, though considering it's working with a `const char *` to store strings, I have to presume the code is quite old.

At any rate, there's nothing about this code which is a C++-specific design choice, and if you want a definitive answer, you need to ask the specific person who wrote the code.

Comment: If you know in advance that you will never do anything with a particular string literal but pass it verbatim to APIs that [can] take `const char *`, then referring to it with a `const char *` variable cuts out a glob of overhead. If there's just one, no big deal, but if there is one for every single function, that could be thousands of static constructors you don't need.